# Node - piping one spawn.child_process to another

Tags: node.js, pipe, child-process, spawn

## Latest update

The problem seems to be in the getModule command...

I've been trying to track down the correct way to pipe stdout from one child_process.spawn into stdin of another. I've done quite a bit of searching, but got stuck here. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong or what I've left out?

Also - I found something indicating this pattern was unpredictable (racy). Can anyone confirm or deny that this will work reliably if I work out the syntax?

```
const getModule = spawn('curl' [url, '-ks']);
const unTar = spawn('tar', ['-xz', '-C', fileName, '--strip-components', 1]);    
getModule.stdout.pipe(unTar.stdin);
```

## Update

In case it helps, here is the error I am getting:

```
Error: TypeError: "file" argument must be a non-empty string
    at getModule.then.catch.err (/xxxxx.js:23:38)
    at <anonymous>
```

Also, I did get this to work

`const getModule = spawn('sh', ['-c', 'curl ' + url + ' -ks | tar -xz -C ' + fileName + '/ --strip-components 1']);`

but I'm trying to pipe the results of one process into another instead.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, it was just a silly missing comma after the curl command in the getModule spawn declaration. I'm unstuck now. :)